# Link Custom CSS and Javascript to Rails After Deployment

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I have a Rails App it's css and js links works fine locally since I have used :

```
    <link href="assets/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/bootswatch.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I Googled more than it should all I find is this [Heroku Guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline) , I'm so confused about the assets pipeline thing! I ran this command as well :

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and it did create some files in the public dir as mentioned in the guide :

Now on Heroku Everything is plain, no design no nothing of Css and JS.

While when I run

> Heroku Logs

This is what I get some serious NO Route Match for the CSS and JS files as follow :

> 2013-06-10T10:06:28.184255+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assetscv.png"):

This is only one line, I get bunch of more of these for other files, and pre generated loggs lines

any help would be appreciated Thanks!

PS:

I tried

```
       <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap-responsiv" %>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootswatch", "font-awesome.css" %>
```

I got bunch of errors and on heroku it says sorry something went wrong

Comment: what are the errors you get when using `stylesheet_link_tag`? Can you find `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap-<hash>.css` in `public/assets`?

Comment: @MartinM this is what I get

`Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
ActionView::Template::Error (bootstrap.css isn't precompiled):

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms
    15:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "bootstrap" %>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In application.rb(config/application.rb)

```
    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true
```

After this in production.rb file(config/environments/production.rb) do like this

```
      # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

      # Code is not reloaded between requests
      config.cache_classes = true

      # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
      config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
      config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

      # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
      #config.serve_static_assets = true

      # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
      config.assets.compress = true

      # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
      config.assets.compile = false

      # Generate digests for assets URLs
      config.assets.digest = true
```

then you should include all your js and css like this,

```
     config.assets.precompile += %w(jquery.js jquery_ujs.js PIE.js check_list.js dom-drag.js jquery-1.4.2.min.js jquery-1.7.1.min.js jquery-1.8.3.js jquery-ui.js jquery.accordion.js jquery.corner.js jquery.countdown.js jquery.dimensions.js jquery.masonry.min.js jquery.tinycarousel.min.js jquery.validationEngine-en.js jquery.validationEngine.js questionnaire.js prototype.js users.js)

     config.assets.precompile += %w(ie7.css ie8.css about_us.css admin_menu.css blog.css default.ultimate.css designer_directory.css designer_directorynew.css drop.css greenstore.css menu.css MenuMatic_dev.css message_view.css product.css setting1.css style1.css styles.css validationEngine.jquery.css)
```

After that precompile using this command

```
     $ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Then `$ heroku restart`

It should work.

For more details please read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: I owe you man! Thanks so much for the awesome guide! SPENT 2 straight days on this!